How to configure React Native android dependencies to use remote repository in gradle build
I am working on a project that is built off the bare minimum template from expo. The build.gradle file is setup to install the dependencies from an internal Artifactory instance.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "artifactoryURL/Google/" }
        maven { url 'artifactoryURL/Maven_Central/' }
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "artifactoryURL/Google/" }
        maven { url 'artifactoryURL/Maven_Central/' }
    }
}


The problem is that the node module dependencies are still trying to install from the public google/maven repositories even though I have specified that the project should be using the remote urls in the build.gradle file.
I have tried also adding the remote repositories in settings.gradle but that didnt work either.
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven { url "artifactoryURL/Google/" }
        maven { url 'artifactoryURL/Maven_Central/' }
        maven { url 'artifactoryURL/Gradle_Plugin_Portal/' }
    }
}

How can I configure the project so that any build.gradle files from node modules install from the remote url I have specified?
